# Windows Phone 8 Universal App - Use JS within C# Code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I am trying to build a WP8.1 Universal App based on an empty C# Project.
In the projectexplorer I can add / creata JS files but I cant find a way to make use of them within the C# project..

So what I am trying to do: Use C# code to access a function written in javascript, located in a JS file within the project.

Is there a way to do so or is this impossible?

Best regards and thanks for you help!
--Flo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not directly possible.

A C# app can host HTML and JavaScript within a WebView control, but it cannot call it directly.

Depending on the details you may be able to load your page into a WebView and call it with the WebView's [InvokeScriptAsync method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx) then get a response via the [ScriptNotify event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.scriptnotify.aspx), but this communication channel is very narrow and you'll likely be better off porting the code to C# if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This is what i wanted to know!